How to validate the first record in an array so that errors for the compact min don't override comment?
I use yup for validation.
I have 3 related required fields: age, name, surname. And an optional comment, the length of which is limited to 10 characters.
Problem: For the first element of the array, if at least one of the fields age, name, surname is not filled in. The error from compact mini overlaps the error from comment.
How to make sure that errors on at least one entry in the array do not overlap the error in the length of the comment.
Source code
App.tsx
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ element: [{ name: '', surname: '', age: '' }] }}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
        onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
          console.log('Sent', values);
          setSubmitting(false);
        }}
      >
        {({
          values,
          handleSubmit,
          isSubmitting,
          errors
        }) => (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <FieldArray name="element">
              {({ remove, push }) => (
                <div>
                  {values.element.length > 0 &&
                    values.element.map((_, index) => (
                      <Inner key={index} index={index} remove={remove} errors={errors}/>
                    ))}
                  <br />
                  <br />
                  <button type="button" onClick={() => push({ name: '', surname: '', age: '' })}>
                    Add
                  </button>
                </div>
              )}
            </FieldArray>
            <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>
              Send
            </button>
          </form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

Inner.tsx
export function Inner({index, remove, errors}) {
  console.log(errors)
  return (
    <div key={index}>
    <Field name={`element.${index}.name`} placeholder="Name" />
    <Field name={`element.${index}.surname`} placeholder="Surname" />
    <Field name={`element.${index}.age`} placeholder="Age" />
    <Field name={`element.${index}.comment`} placeholder="Comment" />
    <button type="button" onClick={() => remove(index)}>
      Delete
    </button>
    </div>
  )
}


validationSchema.ts
export const validationSchema = yup.object({
  element: yup
  .array()
  .of(
    yup.object().shape(
      {
        name: yup.string().when(['surname', 'age'], {
          is: (surname: string | null, age: string | null) =>
            !surname && !age,
          then: yup.string().nullable(),
          otherwise: yup.string().required('Required!!!').nullable(),
        }),
        surname: yup.string().when(['name', 'age'], {
          is: (name: string | null, age: string | null) =>
            !name && !age,
          then: yup.string().nullable(),
          otherwise: yup.string().required('Required!!!').nullable(),
        }),
        age: yup.string().when(['surname', 'name'], {
          is: (surname: string | null, name: string | null) =>
            !surname && !name,
          then: yup.string().nullable(),
          otherwise: yup.string().required('Required!!!').nullable(),
        }),
        comment: yup.string().max(10, 'Max 10 symbols')
      },
      [
        ['surname', 'age'],
        ['name', 'age'],
        ['name', 'surname'],
      ],
    ),
  )
  .compact(
    ({name, surname, age}) =>
      !age && !surname && !name,
  )
  .min(1, 'Min 1 record')
})

Solution
I solved this problem as follows. I added a check using test and skip all possible errors using validate.
Maybe there is some simpler solution?
validationSchema.ts
export const validationSchema = yup.object({
  element: yup
  .array()
  .of(
    yup.object().shape(
      {
        name: yup.string().when(['surname', 'age'], {
          is: (surname: string | null, age: string | null) =>
            !surname && !age,
          then: yup.string().nullable(),
          otherwise: yup.string().required('Required!!!').nullable(),
        }),
        surname: yup.string().when(['name', 'age'], {
          is: (name: string | null, age: string | null) =>
            !name && !age,
          then: yup.string().nullable(),
          otherwise: yup.string().required('Required!!!').nullable(),
        }),
        age: yup.string().when(['surname', 'name'], {
          is: (surname: string | null, name: string | null) =>
            !surname && !name,
          then: yup.string().nullable(),
          otherwise: yup.string().required('Required!!!').nullable(),
        }),
        comment: yup.string().max(10, 'Max 10 symbols')
      },
      [
        ['surname', 'age'],
        ['name', 'age'],
        ['name', 'surname'],
      ],
    ),
  )
  .test('is-not-empty', 'Required', function (req_elements) {
    const isValidRecord =
      req_elements &&
      req_elements.some((record) => record.size || record.nom_length || record.is_one_length);

    if (!isValidRecord) {
      return this.createError({path: `${this.path}`, message: 'Min 1 record'});
    }
    return true;
  }),
})

App.tsx
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ element: [{ name: '', surname: '', age: '' }] }}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
        onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
          console.log('Sent', values);
          setSubmitting(false);
        }}

        validate={(values) => {
          try {
            validationSchema.validateSync(values, { abortEarly: false });
          } catch (err) {
            const errors: Record<string, string> = {}; 
            if (err instanceof ValidationError) {
              err.inner.forEach(error => {
                if (typeof error.path === 'string') { 
                  errors[error.path] = error.message;
                }
              });
            }
            return errors;
          }
        }}
      >
        {({
          values,
          handleSubmit,
          isSubmitting,
          errors
        }) => (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <FieldArray name="element">
              {({ remove, push }) => (
                <div>
                  {values.element.length > 0 &&
                    values.element.map((_, index) => (
                      <Inner key={index} index={index} remove={remove} errors={errors}/>
                    ))}
                  <br />
                  <br />
                  <button type="button" onClick={() => push({ name: '', surname: '', age: '' })}>
                    Add
                  </button>
                </div>
              )}
            </FieldArray>
            <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>
              Send
            </button>
          </form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
}

Thanks in advance for your help!
Additional Information:
yup version: 0.32.11
Framework: React
